# yui checkbox treeview get node and make it as checked

Tags: checkbox, treeview, yui

I am using yui3 [CheckBoxTreeView.](http://haizaar.github.io/yui3-gallery/gallery-yui3treeview-ng/api/classes/CheckBoxTreeView.html)

I can give each [CheckBoxTreeNode](http://haizaar.github.io/yui3-gallery/gallery-yui3treeview-ng/api/classes/CheckBoxTreeNode.html) an Id, but I don't know how to retrieve this node after I click external link and make it as checked status.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, Stack Overflow don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated". [See "Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)